# Geodesics don't exist for this connectIon?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

*This is a long one, so thanks in advance if you actually read the whole thing...*

I'm reviewing Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds* and am trying to discover the geometric implications of torsion in a connection by just coming up with a sample connection on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and trying to solve e.g. the geodesic equations and parallel transport equations. I'm going to pick a connection $\nabla$ with Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ gives as

$$\Gamma_{11}^1= 0,\ \Gamma_{11}^2= 1,\ \Gamma_{12}^1= -1,\ \Gamma_{12}^2= 0,\\
\Gamma_{21}^1= 0,\ \Gamma_{21}^2=1 ,\ \Gamma_{22}^1= -1,\ \Gamma_{22}^2= 0.$$

You can check that this connection *is* compatible with the Riemannian connection, but clearly it's not the Euclidean connection. So I'd expect its geodesics would look strange. According to Lee, a curve $x(t)=(x^i(t))$ is a geodesic if and only if its components satisfy the equations

$$\ddot{x}^k + \dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j\Gamma_{ij}^k = 0.$$

Using my Christoffel symbols, I get eight equations:

$$\ddot{x}^1 + \dot{x}^1\dot{x}^1\Gamma_{11}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 + \dot{x}^1\dot{x}^1\Gamma_{11}^2 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^1 + \dot{x}^1\dot{x}^2\Gamma_{12}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 + \dot{x}^1\dot{x}^2\Gamma_{12}^2 = 0,\\
\ddot{x}^1 + \dot{x}^2\dot{x}^1\Gamma_{21}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 + \dot{x}^2\dot{x}^1\Gamma_{21}^2 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^1 + \dot{x}^2\dot{x}^2\Gamma_{22}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 + \dot{x}^2\dot{x}^2\Gamma_{22}^2 = 0,$$

which simplify to

$$\ddot{x}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 + \dot{x}^1\dot{x}^1= 0,\ \ddot{x}^1 - \dot{x}^1\dot{x}^2 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 = 0,\\
\ddot{x}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2 + \dot{x}^2\dot{x}^1 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^1 - \dot{x}^2\dot{x}^2 = 0,\ \ddot{x}^2= 0.$$

But now you can easily see that both components of your curve $x^1(t)$ and $x^2(t)$ must be *constant*, which seems to say that the only geodesics in this connection are constant paths with zero velocity. But doesn't the existence theorem say that we should be able to find geodesics with any initial position and velocity? Have I broken ODE's?

Comment: How do you get $8$ equations? The geodesic equation is just $2$ equations: $k=1$ and $k=2$. The $i,j$ are summed over.

Comment: Wow, you are so right. I really need to pay more attention to the placement of my indices before I start wasting my time writing down all of these different iterations. Thank you!